# Why is there high packet loss when transferring across wireless network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, tomato

Normal internet browsing behavior does not trigger packet loss, but when I am doing a significant, sustained wireless to wireless transfers[0], packet loss increases to 30-50%. Wired devices are unaffected.

This is a remote location so I don't have the luxury of bringing all my troubleshooting equipment or running to the local electronics store.

What could be causing this issue? Hardware failing over time? Bad firmware? I have the same exact hardware and firmware in multiple locations and they do not exhibit this behavior.

Setup:

- hardware: Asus WL-520GU
- firmware: Tomato v1.28
- settings: default, no wireless password, no QOS
- channel: no other wireless networks in the area
- the wireless router is not adjacent to a microwave

[0] `rsync` transfers between two laptops.

Comment: Is it a wireless-to-wireless transfer that has the problem? Are the two endpoints of the transfer fairly far from each other (like on opposite sides of the AP)? You could be running into a "hidden node problem" where your Wi-Fi clients' transmissions are colliding with each other, but only the AP can see that it's happening. Try setting the RTS/CTS threshold down to, say, 1000 and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, wireless to wireless. They are normally far from the AP, but can reproduce with both laptops next to router. Changing RTS threshold to 1000 made no difference.